# Cannot use az pipelines on microsoft hosted agent

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to run an azure cli command to get the previous commit hash of the last succesfull build;

`az pipelines runs list --top 1 --result succeeded --status completed --pipeline-ids 12`

I'm having some issues because the `az` command seems to be missing, but only when i try to run `az` from azure pipelines.

I'm running a microsoft self hosted agent and i have installed `az` via the MSI installer. Additionally i used the powershell gallery to install `az` (Only because it did not work oob).

The az command is accesible when i run it via powershell (as admin). The build agent does run under `nt authority\network service` which has given me issues in the past, but running under that user the following works as-is;

cmd stat powershell under th
`psexec.exe -i -u "nt authority\network service" "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

powershell;

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> whoami
nt authority\network service
PS C:\Windows\system32> az --version
azure-cli                         2.49.0

core                              2.49.0
telemetry                          1.0.8

Extensions:
azure-devops                      0.26.0

Dependencies:
msal                              1.20.0
azure-mgmt-resource               22.0.0

Python location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python.exe'
Extensions directory 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.azure\cliextensions'

Python (Windows) 3.10.10 (tags/v3.10.10:aad5f6a, Feb  7 2023, 17:05:00) [MSC v.1929 32 bit (Intel)]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal


Your CLI is up-to-date.
```

So it seems this works. I thought that maybe `-NoProfile` would be an issue but it seems not to be.

Then where the issue lies, in azure pipelines.

Build script is as follows;

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      whoami
      if(Get-Command az -errorAction SilentlyContinue) {
          Write-Host "Az installed"
      } else {
          Write-Host "Installing az..."
          $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows -OutFile .\AzureCLI.msi; Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I AzureCLI.msi /quiet'; Remove-Item .\AzureCLI.msi;
          Write-Host "Done"
          az --version
      }
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
  displayName: 'Maybe install AZ cli'

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      whoami
      $resp = (az pipelines runs list --top 1 --result succeeded --status completed --pipeline-ids 12)
      $json_str = "$resp"
      $json = ConvertFrom-Json $json_str
      $previousCommit = $json[0].sourceVersion
      
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path .\WebApi\bin\$(buildConfiguration)\net7.0\Artifacts | Out-Null
      
      Write-Host (& git log $previousCommit..HEAD --stat > .\WebApi\bin\$(buildConfiguration)\net7.0\Artifacts\commit-log.txt)
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
  displayName: 'Save commit log'
```

This only executes the first command;

```
2023-07-04T06:53:39.8770769Z ##[section]Starting: Maybe install AZ cli
2023-07-04T06:53:39.9106947Z ==============================================================================
2023-07-04T06:53:39.9107247Z Task         : PowerShell
2023-07-04T06:53:39.9107391Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
2023-07-04T06:53:39.9107566Z Version      : 2.220.0
2023-07-04T06:53:39.9107690Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-07-04T06:53:39.9107828Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
2023-07-04T06:53:39.9108073Z ==============================================================================
2023-07-04T06:53:43.4440161Z Generating script.
2023-07-04T06:53:43.5177859Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-07-04T06:53:43.5563390Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\agent\_work\_temp\4a509abf-bbb8-434f-9dec-e4f295ed15da.ps1'"
2023-07-04T06:53:44.0060012Z nt authority\network service
2023-07-04T06:53:45.4666261Z Installing az...
2023-07-04T06:53:52.2658414Z Done
2023-07-04T06:53:52.4480915Z az : The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
2023-07-04T06:53:52.4482251Z spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
2023-07-04T06:53:52.4482940Z At C:\agent\_work\_temp\4a509abf-bbb8-434f-9dec-e4f295ed15da.ps1:11 char:5
2023-07-04T06:53:52.4483551Z +     az --version
2023-07-04T06:53:52.4483795Z +     ~~
2023-07-04T06:53:52.4485226Z     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (az:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
2023-07-04T06:53:52.4486971Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
2023-07-04T06:53:52.4496285Z  
2023-07-04T06:53:52.5861129Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2023-07-04T06:53:52.6431422Z ##[section]Finishing: Maybe install AZ cli
```

This seems to fail to install install `az`. This seems like a permission issue - and i'm fine with installing it manually out of the pipeline, but as we can see `az` fails here.

Why is the `az` command not recognized when running `az` in a pipeline even though i installed it?

Comment: Did you try not running ` az --version` in the first step when you install cli? I guess that path is not updated in this step and can be reachable from the next step.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I did, unfortunately it does not matter. `az` should be available anyways..